# Gradle sync finishes, but files have always "changed" and it wants to sync again

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I have recently gotten a new computer and installed Android Studio and pulled my project from git.  Android Studio keeps displaying the message

"Gradle files have changed since last project sync.  A project sync may be necessary for the IDE to work properly."

[image: header image]

Image at the top of every file.  When I "Sync Now" it syncs properly and finishes, reporting:

```
Executing tasks: [:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugSources, :BrewingPrograms:generateDebugTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:BrewingPrograms:preBuild
:BrewingPrograms:preDebugBuild
:BrewingPrograms:checkDebugManifest
:BrewingPrograms:preReleaseBuild
:BrewingPrograms:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:prepareDebugDependencies
:BrewingPrograms:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:preDebugTestBuild
:BrewingPrograms:prepareDebugTestDependencies
:BrewingPrograms:compileDebugTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:processDebugTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:compileDebugTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:mergeDebugTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:mergeDebugTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:processDebugTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:BrewingPrograms:generateDebugTestSources UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.208 secs
```

But not matter how many times I do it, or invalidate caches and do it again, the yellow bar remains and it wants to Sync Now.
[image: sync now]

My top level gradle file looks like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.1'
        classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.4.+"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I have the same behavior on both the 0.8.4 release as well as the canary channel 0.9.2 release of Android Studio.
My Gradle settings currently `Use default gradle wrapper`

What else to try?

Comment: @user2025083: Same problem here. How it solved for you?

Comment: Did you fixed that  issue help me guys.